# Authorize.net ARB endless subscription

Tags: payment-gateway, subscription, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I am working on ARB subscription with endless time of subscription, and member will charge monthly for unlimited time, until he unsubscribe. I have entered "totalOccurrences" as "9999" but what will be "expirationDate" for endless subscription ?

My second question is, how can I create two types of subscription with same credit card number and other information?

Answer (score 0):

> I have entered "totalOccurrences" as "9999" but what will be "expirationDate" for endless subscription ?

This is the expiration date of the credit card they are using. Although the subscription will never end, the credit card will expire at some point. You will be responsible for updating it when it does.

> how can I create two types of subscription with same credit card number and other information ?

Entering a different invoice number for each subscription will allow you to establish subscriptions with the same user and credit card information.

Comment: Can you please answer of my comment, i have posted in Answer? Thank you.